# Прошу подсказать, как с помощью Node.js(Именно Node.js) я могу вычилить у песни BPM(Количество ударов в минуту) и тональность(Ноту) той самой песни

Tags: node.js, express

Приветсвую всех! Хочу узнать, может быть, кто-то сталкивался с задачей вычисления количества ударов в минуту и тональности у определенной песни?

Я посомтрел достаточно ресурсов, увидел модули только для вычисления количсетва ударов в минуту(BPM), может быть, кто-нибудь что-то знает об этом? Или поделитесь своей точкой зрения о том, как можно усовершенствовать модуль [bpm-detective](https://github.com/tornqvist/bpm-detective) или [music-tempo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-tempo). Спасибо!

Comment: https://github.com/peterkhayes/pitchfinder